# How to show images as pixelated instead of blurry on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm working on an app where I have a lot of small photos / drawings that are in a pixelated style. Because they're pixelated, they're very small, about two times smaller than I'd like them to appear on the screen. Whenever I do this, instead of seeing the same sharp photo, with each pixel slightly larger, I see a blurred version of the small one. I was wondering if there was a setting to turn that off, and show each pixel slightly larger, and with a sharp edge. I'd rather avoid the hassle of processing each image and multiplying the pixel sizes, but if there's an easy way to do that I'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: `Because they're pixelated, they're very small` I don't understand this statement. Ok your images are small, but is them being pixellated really the reason why?

Comment: Well, they have to be small so when you enlargen them they look pixelated.

Comment: They don't have to. You can pixelate normal images with a filter and keep their size unchanged. There's no relation. You can do that at any scale/size/resolution.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help.